# Notepad++ find feature searches up the document or down the document. How to search all over

Tags: notepad++

If I search for a word using FIND in WordPad, it automatically searches down the document, when it reaches the bottom of the document it automatically jumps to the top and continues the search.

In Notepad++ this does not appear to be default behaviour.

In Notepad++ I am presented with a choice of searching, under the pane called `direction` - either `up` the document, or `down` the document. This is a pain, if I knew where the word I wanted to find was, I would not use the functionality.

[image]

Is there a way to mimic similar behavior of WordPad's find in Notepad++ (where I iterate through each matching string one at a time) and not have to manually change the direction to search the entire document?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function you want can be made available by checking the "Wrap around" checkbox.

[image]

Comment: Was it really this simple? :S Thanks

Comment: One of the few cases where a oneliner was the appropriate answer (since you can see what is talked about on the screenshot in the question)